# Unit x.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument

Tags: python-3.x, service, systemd

I tried to use systemd to keep my Discord bot running on my VPS. I used the exact same setup as my old bot, but when I modified `ExecStart`, I got an error

Old setup:

```
[Unit]
Description=Red-DiscordBotV3
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redbot
User=laggron
Group=laggron
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/username/Red-DiscordBot/red.py --no-prompt
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

New setup:

```
[Unit]
Description=Red-DiscordBotV3
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redbot
User=laggron
Group=laggron
ExecStart=/home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/ -m redbot Red --dev --no-prompt
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(New setup is using a virtualenv, and python3.6 is installed from source)

What I got:

```
danny_brown5544@ref:/etc/systemd/system $ 
Failed to start redV3.service: Unit redV3.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status redV3.service' for details.
```

Typing `systemctl status redV3.service`:

```
danny_brown5544@ref:/home/danny_brown5544/Red-DiscordBot $ 
● redV3.service - Red-DiscordBotV3
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jan 21 11:04:55 ref systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redV3.service:8] Executable path specifies a directory, ignoring: /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/ /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redbot/__main__.py Red --dev --no-prompt
Jan 21 11:04:55 ref systemd[1]: redV3.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jan 21 11:06:12 ref systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redV3.service:8] Executable path specifies a directory, ignoring: /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/ /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redbot/__main__.py Red --dev --no-prompt
Jan 21 11:06:12 ref systemd[1]: redV3.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jan 21 11:11:54 ref systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redV3.service:8] Executable path specifies a directory, ignoring: /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/ /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redbot/__main__.py --dev --no-prompt
Jan 21 11:11:54 ref systemd[1]: redV3.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jan 24 15:34:20 ref systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redV3.service:8] Executable path specifies a directory, ignoring: /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/ -m redbot Red --dev --no-prompt
Jan 24 15:34:20 ref systemd[1]: redV3.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jan 24 15:35:34 ref systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redV3.service:8] Executable path specifies a directory, ignoring: /home/laggron/rewrite/lib/python3.6/ -m redbot Red --dev --no-prompt
Jan 24 15:35:34 ref systemd[1]: redV3.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Comment: did you `systemctl daemon-reload` between changes ?

Comment: @papey yeah I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exec start is pointing towards a directory. Remove the trailing `/` on it, and verify that's the path to the python you need with `which python` while having the virtualenv active